# system call during pipe lining of two commands in unix

Tags: unix, systems-programming

when we write `ls -l | wc -l` command on terminal what system calls are made internally at kernel level??
and How can we verify all those system calls made.

Comment: Look at the source code for these commands. I think they are all in `coreutils` package.

Comment: you could study the source code of both

Comment: Or use `strace -o /tmp/ls.out ls -l | strace -o /tmp/wc.out wc -l` to trace each system call for you... (assuming this is Linux, anyway - on Solaris it would be `truss` instead of `strace`; AIX and other *NIXen have similar facilities, but those are the two I know best...)

Comment: @Aleksandar I am not asking about the system call of each individual commands but the when they are used in conjunction pipelining.

Comment: @Serge how can i get system call used when both are used in pipelining by reading source code.. can't you explain the system call used during pipelining.

Comment: @twalberg thanks yours reply worked:)

Comment: It is not different from normal situation when input/output is done without pipelining: `ls` uses write to the FD#1; `wc` uses read ferm fd#1. The only difference that the shell program created the pipe _before_ it created both processes and these processes created with pipe's FDs instead of FD's of tty device.

Comment: @Rahul: If you found the working solution for the question, you could answer your own question and close it.